# Comparing numbers or using prime numbers?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, combinations

I'm writing a program that generates bingo card numbers. The bingo card is composed of 5 columns, 4 numbers for each column. For the first column can only contain numbers 1-8, second 9-16, and so on (upto 40).

So in the database, what I did is I have two tables for this. The first table is for the column numbers. Each column contains a unique set of numbers (70 sets for each column, which is a combination of 8 taken 4). For 5 columns, I will have 350 sets. The second table is the card numbers. This is composed of 5 columns, each corresponding to the row for B, I, N, G, O. All in all, there are 1,680,700,000. possible combinations for this table. I did this way because each cards are duplicated for each game, only control numbers for cards are unique.

I want to track the winning card for every drawn number. I need the tracking as fast as I could, cause where talking about millions of cards here. I thought of 2 options on doing this:

First, checking each drawn number if it exists on the cards, minimizing the card pool for each draw.

Second, associating a unique prime number for each number(1-40), multiplying them and associate the product to the column (which I call the prime index). The 5 prime indexes, for each column, is multiplied and the product is associated to each card/combination (which I call the card index). When a number is drawn, the associated prime number is divided from the card index, checking if the drawn number is a factor of the card index. Each consecutive draw reduce the card index (for each card in the pool), and thus reduced to 1 if a winning card exists. I will be using MySQL and Java. Which of these 2 techniques is the faster approach? I also do consider the memory space, load, etc., but it is more important to me the speed of the tracking. Thanks a lot!

P.S. Sorry for the long explanation. I just want to clarify things. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be really fast just keep your 24 million cards in memory while they are needed and just do a simple comparation. Using the database for this is overkill and just makes everything more difficult. RAM is not expensive anymore.

Comment: I cannot do it without a database, because I also track the OWNER of the cards and where it is purchased? And cards are duplicated for each game, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: +1 This is certainly one way to do it. Even with 24 Million cards, containing 40 64-bit numbers (if you store the card numbers in a large, 64-bit number, which in itself is overkill), you're still only looking at 40*8 = 320 MB of RAM to store the entire set of possible cards.

Comment: In terms of the owner of the cards, you could still do this in memory. I mean, a database is, in some sense, just a way to store large amounts of data that you couldn't otherwise store in RAM. If you need to store the cards in the database for some reason, you could always save them when your application closes. 320MB of RAM, unless you're on some embedded system that has a very tight RAM limit, is basically a very small amount of RAM.

Comment: actually it's a billion card combinations. Is it still possible?

Comment: If its worth spending one cent per card on hardware, you can spend $240K, which is enough to buy a server with 1 TB of memory with plenty to spare. I suspect your budget is smaller, but that you won't have 24 million active cards to keep track of either.

Comment: @Jairo, billion is still possible, unless this is homework, what is a realistic number of active bingo cards will you have?

Comment: Some of the biggest lotteries in the world have 5 million players. Perhaps that is more realist number to work with.

Comment: You can keep the owner ID in memory and update/lookup database according to the results determined in memory.

Comment: Actually, I don't have statistics of possible number of active cards. But it's for a nationwide business.

Comment: @Jairo, There must be a point at which you can say, if its that successful, we would spend more money on the solution.  e.g. you are regularly having 1 million clients/cards, do you think that would justify more budget?

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly 70^5=1,680,700,000 possible cards. There is no need to store the cards itself. You can calculate the numbers on the card directly, with only the index. The other way around, given numbers find indices of cards, is just a little bit harder.

For example, card #1421934546. Putting this in base 70 gives: `59 15 40 50 46`. (I mean `46 + 70*50 + 70^2*40 + 70^3*15 + 70^4*59 = 1421934546`). So, the first column is the 46th(actually 47th because off-by-one) take of the possible 70 takes.

Given the drawn numbers, you can quickly find the columns that match. For example, with numbers 1,2 and 3. There are 5 sets in the first column that match, `1234`, `1235`, `1236`, `1237` and `1238`. So, all matching cards have % 70 one of those 5 ids. If you find all the possible sets for each columns, the Cartesian product will give all matching cards.

Comment: I will use prime numbers instead. It's much quicker, i think, than using base 70 with additions and multiplications

Comment: @Jairo - Uhm. My approach is really different. I mean, you don't search for the winning card, you simply compute it. That's faster even with additions and multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to arrange the data in memory the same as you have on the card. e.g. if you have N squares which can be either selected or not selected, a BitSet may be a good choice.  This uses 1 bit per square (with some overhead).

Say you have up to 64 squares, this is one long value (64-bits).  If you have 1 million cards. This will take up 8 MB of memory.  Once you determine which card(s) are winners, you can determine who the owners are. (This could be stored in a database)

Say you sell a card to every adult in the US. (AFAIK, no lottery has ever been this popular) At say one dollar each, you would be bringing 200 million dollars. You would need 1.6 GB of memory which would fit into a 4 GB server costing about $500 easily. You could buy a 16 GB server for about $1000 just to be sure. ;)